# How to use multiples routes for same resources

Tags: kotlin, ktor

I have many URI for same resource in Ktor. To avoid to repeat too many lines, I found this solution:

```kotlin
routing {

    get("/", home())
    get("/index", home())
    get("/home", home())

    ...
    
}

private fun home(): suspend PipelineContext<Unit, ApplicationCall>.(Unit) -> Unit =
    {
        val parameters = ...
        call.respond(ThymeleafContent("/index.html", parameters))
    }
```

Is there more elegant solution like this:

```kotlin
routing {

    get("/", "/index", "/home") {
        val parameters = ...
        call.respond(ThymeleafContent("/index.html", parameters))
    }
    
    ...
    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I know of compressing that would be to create a global variable containing the home-paths and then `forEach` it.

```kotlin
val homePaths = arrayOf("/path1", "/path2", ...)

...

routing {
    homePaths.forEach { path -> get(path, home()) }
}
```

A cool feature would be to be able to specify a regular expression as the input of the routing method.

And something that you can cook for yourself is a KTX that does such thing.

```kotlin
fun Routing.get(varargs routes: String, call: suspend PipelineContext<Unit, ApplicationCall>.(Unit)) {
    for (route in routes) {
        get(route, call)
    }
}
```

And finally call it like:

```kotlin
routing {
    get("/path1", "/path2") { /* your handling method */}
}
```

Comment: It's so simple that I wonder how I did not think about ! Thanks